# PyQt widget absolute position inside QVBoxLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm working on some PyQt5 project, I came from Web Development and I stuck with some trivial task. 
I have some QVBoxLayout and inside it I placed QWidget just to add it some background color via CSS. After that I wanted to put some image,  **self.img** 
 just right at the center of QWidget. But I couldn't manage how to do it. 
It just renders my Image below of the QWidget nad that's all.

I tried to use *move(x,y)* method, tried to use background image for QWidget but I failed. So I really stuck with it.

I tried to search some possible ways to solve it but I didn't found anything which could help me. 
If someone could help me I'll be very appreciate for any input. Thanks for any help.

To be honest - I'm new in PyQt. Sorry if I asked some dummy question but I really need help.

Here is my code

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap



class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(TopContentBlock(self))
        self.layout.addWidget(BottomContentBlock(self))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.setMinimumSize(640,400)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.pressing = False


class TopContentBlock(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TopContentBlock, self).__init__();
        self.parent = parent;
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.content = QWidget()
        self.content.setFixedSize(640, 250)
        self.content.setStyleSheet("""
         background-color: #67BEC3;
        """)

        self.img = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap('main_illustration.png')
        self.img.setPixmap(pixmap)
        print(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        self.img.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        #self.img.setFixedSize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        self.layout.addWidget(self.img)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.content)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class BottomContentBlock(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(BottomContentBlock, self).__init__();
        self.parent = parent;
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.content = QWidget()
        self.content.setFixedSize(640, 400)
        self.content.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: cyan;
        """)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.content)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


import resources_new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QPoint, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
                             QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPixmap


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(TopContentBlock(self))
        self.layout.addWidget(BottomContentBlock(self))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
#        self.layout.addStretch(1)
        self.setMinimumSize(640,600)                         # 600
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
#?        self.pressing = False


class TopContentBlock(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TopContentBlock, self).__init__();
#?        self.parent = parent;
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.content = QWidget()
        self.content.setFixedSize(640, 200)                  #(640, 250)
        self.content.setStyleSheet("""
         background-color: #67BEC3;
        """)

        self.img = QLabel()
        self.img.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)                # +++

        pixmap = QPixmap('im.png')                           #('main_illustration.png')
#        self.img.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.img.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(200, 200,           # +++
                                         Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, 
                                         Qt.FastTransformation))
#        self.img.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        #self.img.setFixedSize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        self.layout.addWidget(self.img)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.content)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)                            # +++
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class BottomContentBlock(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(BottomContentBlock, self).__init__();
        self.parent = parent;
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.content = QWidget()
        self.content.setFixedSize(640, 200)               #(640, 400)
        self.content.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: cyan;
        """)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.content)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QPoint, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
                             QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPixmap


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(TopContentBlock(self))
        self.layout.addWidget(BottomContentBlock(self))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
#        self.layout.addStretch(1)
        self.setMinimumSize(640,400)                         # 400
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
#?        self.pressing = False


class TopContentBlock(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TopContentBlock, self).__init__();
#?        self.parent = parent;
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

#        self.content = QWidget()                            # --- <---
        self.setFixedSize(640, 200)                          # --- .content              
        self.setStyleSheet("""                               
         background-color: #67BEC3;
        """)                                                 # --- .content 

        self.img = QLabel()
        self.img.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)                # +++

        pixmap = QPixmap('im.png')                           #('main_illustration.png')
#        self.img.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.img.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(200, 200,           # +++
                                         Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, 
                                         Qt.FastTransformation))
#        self.img.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        #self.img.setFixedSize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        self.layout.addWidget(self.img)
#        self.layout.addWidget(self.content)                 # ---
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)                            # +++
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class BottomContentBlock(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(BottomContentBlock, self).__init__();
        self.parent = parent;
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.content = QWidget()
        self.content.setFixedSize(640, 200)               #(640, 400)
        self.content.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: cyan;
        """)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.content)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi S.Nick. Thanks for the help. But the image behaviour isn't as it expected. It renders above of the Widget which has #67BEC3  bg color. I would like to have this image right at the center of the colored widget. Now this image just like the independent first row with white background. Is there exists any way to have 2 rows and place the image at the center of the first row?

Comment: Thank you Nick! It works like a charm. I didn't know that there is exists a possibility to set style to VBoxLayout. Btw, an one question: does it means than in PyQt we can't position our QWidgets absolutely inside other QWidgets?

Comment: The Qt layout system provides a simple and powerful way of automatically arranging child widgets within a widget to ensure that they make good use of the available space.